# Why is $\int e^{-t}u(t) dt = (1-e^{-t})u(t) + Constant$?

Tags: calculus, convolution, signal-processing, integration-by-parts

How do you solve $\int e^{-t}u(t) dt $? In which u(t) is the unit step function.
 $\int e^{-t}u(t) dt  = (1-e^{-t})u(t) + Constant$ But what are the intermediate steps?

Unit step

1. u(t) = 
   \begin{cases} 
    0 & \mbox{for } t < 0  \\
   \\
    1 & \mbox{for } t > 0 
   \end{cases}

Integration by parts:

$f=-e^{-t}$

$g=u(t)$

$\int f'g = fg - \int fg'$

$\int e^{-t}u(t) = -e^{t}u(t) - \int -e^{-t}\delta(t) = -e^t u(t) + u(t) = (1-e^t ) u(t)$

Comment: The proof would use the *definition* of the unit step function.  Why not write that down and plug in and see what happens?

Comment: @GEdgar If t>0: $ \int e^{-t}u(t) dt = \int e^{-t} dt = -e^{-t} + C$, but how about the 1 in front of it.

Comment: The integral should be continuous.  This explains the $1$.

Comment: @GEdgar Is there something wrong with integration by parts as done in the question?

Comment: It looks OK now... It is the same as Gordon's answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c\left(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}\right)$ a test function; we have
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}\right)u(t)\varphi'(t)\mathrm{d}t & = \int_0^{+\infty}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}\right)\varphi'(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
& = \left[\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}\right)\varphi(t)\right]_0^{+\infty}-\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-t}\varphi(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
& = -\int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{e}^{-t}u(t)\varphi(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align}
because $\varphi$ has compact support. So the derivative in the sense of distributions of $t\mapsto \left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-t}\right)u(t)$ is given by $t\mapsto\mathrm{e}^{-t}\varphi(t)u(t)$.

Comment: You don't need to invoke distributions for this.

Comment: @Nicolas: Sorry, I don't understand this, since I haven't learned about φ and φ' and distributions at the university yet.

Comment: @Nokad If the question is to find a primitive, then you need distributions because the (unit) step function is not differentiable in the usual sense.

Comment: @Nicolas I learned the use the the Dirac delta function as the derivative of the unit step function and the Ramp function as the primitive of the unit step function for these signal processing related equations.

Comment: @Nokad Dirac delta function is actually a distribution, and derivative involving step or Dirac delta functions are in sense of distributions. So if you want a primitive, it is in the sense of distribution. If you looked for an indefinite integral, you can refer to the answer of Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int e^{-t} u(t) dt &= \int_{-\infty}^t e^{-s} u(s) ds +C\\
&= \begin{cases}
C & t \leq 0\\
\int_0^te^{-s}  ds +C & t >0\\
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
C & t \leq 0\\
\big(1-e^{-t}\big) +C & t >0\\
\end{cases} \\
&= \big(1-e^{-t}\big) u(t) + C.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can I ask you why you substitute t=s and how you got upperbound=t from an indefinite integral?

Comment: To replace $t$ by $s$ is for clarity purpose. The integral up to $t$ is a special case of the primitive or anti-derivative, while we add the constant $C$ to make it to the general anti-derivative, that is, the indefinite integral.